# error: no devices/emulators found, Run React Native on Genymotion

Tags: reactjs, native, genymotion

iam using genymotion emulator to run react native on mac, 
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.53.0
node:v8.9.4 
while i running react-native run-android i got error like this
...

```
.....

Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'GNexus5623 - 6.0' for app:debug
    11:17:39 E/DeviceMonitor: Adb connection Error:EOF
    11:17:39 E/DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 1
    Installed on 1 device.

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL

    Total time: 14.691 secs

    This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
    Starting the app (/Users/yan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.vero/com.vero.MainActivity...
    error: no devices/emulators found
```

does anyone give me solution, thanks

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me (For debian based systems only), make sure you have configured genymotion to use your android Sdk by:

- Open Genymotion
- Click on the settings icon
- go to ADB tab
- Click on use Custom Sdk tools.
- navigate to the folder you downloaded

and then add this to your .bashrc

```
export PATH=/home/{username}/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/{username}/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```